# How to call function indirectly in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, mutablemap

Assume I have a mutableMap:

```
val MM = mutableMapOf()
```

Now I define a function as a method for it:

```
MM["testF"] = fun () {
  println("WOW")
}
```

Now I want to call it in another place:

```
val MMTF = MM["testF"] as Function<*>
MMTF() <-- NOT WORKING
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You'll definitely have to explicitly specify its type as `() -> Unit`, not just `Function<*>`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will print bar

```
fun main() {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String, () -> Any>()
    map["foo"] = {
        println("bar")
    }
    run(map["foo"]!!)
}
```